# Extraer valores de select con curl php

Tags: curl

Hola amigos necesito extraer los valores de un select de una página con CURL.

Esta es la estructura.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="selectError3">Lote</label>
        <div class="controls">
                        <select name="lote" >
                                    <option value='0' selected>Seleccione un lote</option>
                                    <option value='201912027921'>201912027921</option>
                                    <option value='202001000802'>202001000802</option>
                                    <option value='202001002185'>202001002185</option>
                                    <option value='202001002600'>202001002600</option>
                                    <option value='202001002616'>202001002616</option>  
                        </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

necesito extraer solo los valores para almacenarlos en una variable con php
Gracias

este codigo realizo las peticiones con curl

```
$url2="https://xyz.com";
$sesion2 = curl_init($url2);
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); //muestra cabecera
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware
$content2 = curl_exec($ch2); //almaceno la pagina en la variable
print_r($content2); //imrpimo la pagina
```

pero necesito obtener los valores de los select y guardarlos en variables

Comment: Y que has intentado hacer? Podrías copiar tu código, para seguir guiándote

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. ¿Te refieres a traer el HTML para luego obtener de él los valores del `select`?

Comment: exactamente , es lo que necesito , y luego guardarlos en variables

Comment: @EnriqueOrozco Puedes echarle un vistazo a librerías como Simple HTML DOM (https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) que te pueden servir para extraer el contenido de elementos de un fichero HTML en particular.

Comment: Pero si la página donde está el select es tuya, ¿por qué no programas mejor na especie de API que sirva los datos en forma de un JSON y así los obtienes vía una URL?